# Parsing text file in Python by delimiter \r\r\n

Tags: python-3.x

I am developing a sample code for my customer and haven't done programming in python before. I am reading a text file from google cloud bucket

```py
bucket = read_storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

 # get bucket data as blob
blob = bucket.get_blob("test.txt")


 # convert to string
json_data_string = blob.download_as_string()
```

extracted text is in format below.

```py
b'**MSV|^\$|MS40C\2.2\rPID|||2355|taylor\4.4|9112540\rOB|1|NM|NA^1**\r\r\n**MSV|^\$|MS40C\2.3\rPID|||2355|Mark\4.4|9112541\rOB|12|NM|NA^1**\r\r\n**MSV|^\$|MS40C\2.3\rPID|||2355|taylor\4.4|9112540|AX|22\rOB|14|NM|NA^1**\r\r\n'
```

I want to split the string by '\r\r\n', loop through the 3 substrings highlighted in bold. What's the easiest way to do this? Pls let me know if you need additional info

Comment: try ```json_data_string.split("\r\r\n")``` which produces a list which you can loop through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, you can split strings by certain characters or groups of characters using the `.split` method. This returns a list which you can iterate over as shown below. You can either pass a bytes-like object in the `split` method, or decode the `json_data_string`

```py
for data in json_data_string.decode('utf8').split('\r\r\n'):
  # do something
```

or

```py
for data in json_data_string.split(b'\r\r\n'):
  # do something
```

You can obviously replace the `'\r\r\n'` with something else to split the string with a different delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the other answer, the `.split()` method would be the easiest way to achieve what you're looking for. The only difference is that using `.split('\r\r\n')` on your string won't work because `\` is an escape character.

You will need to escape, the escape character by running the following method on your string `.split('\\r\\r\\n')`.

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need to do this, because the values in the string are also the escape characters